# Can I attach a 4inch toilet raiser to an airline toilet seat as I’m unable to get off a normal toilet alone with my disability

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, accessibility, toilets

I have a muscle wasting disease and am unable to get off a normal toilet- we take a 4” toilet seat that easily screws onto toilets when we travel (with wipes and always clean it etc) it fits standard toilets- will it fit on a plane toilet? Otherwise I need to be lifted off and 2 people don’t fit in- so the door would need to be left open- what happens when disabled people need to use the toilet?

Comment: Which airline(s) are you planning on travelling with? This article https://www.reducedmobility.eu/20220622766/TheNews/which-airlines-say-where-accessible-toilets-on-planes-are has a list of accessibility by major airlines

Comment: does it fit on top of an existing seat or replace it? In some planes I've flown on, the toilet is part of a larger panel so I don't think there's an easy way to access the existing seat's bolts.

Comment: Airplane toilets are not designed to accommodate standard toilet seats or assistive devices. The best course of action would be to contact the airline prior to your flight and inform them of your needs. They may be able to arrange for an aisle wheelchair or other accommodations to assist you in using the restroom. Additionally, some airlines may have accessible lavatories on certain planes or offer a private restroom for those with disabilities. It's always best to communicate your needs in advance to ensure a smooth and comfortable travel experience.